# jqgrid and tinyMCE or FCKEditor

Tags: jqgrid, tinymce, fckeditor

I've been trying for ages to add any kind of editor to jqGrid. so basically i want to be able to select a row and a modal opens and if it's type= textarea to show the editor.

Is this possible?
I found a lot of post with vague snippets of code but no real implementation.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.
Andrés.